# in app launching notes application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton

I am making an app and would like to have a function that links to the notes app of iOS 5. Is there any code for that? e.g. i have a UIButton and when users press on it, it closes the application and launches the iOS notes application.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Notes there is no URL scheme. Apple provides a reference for available schemes of their apps here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 4):

You haven't mentioned whether this is for AppStore or for jailbroken/in-house development. If the latter, you can use the `SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier()` function from the SpringBoardServices private framework:

```
SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFSTR("com.apple.notes"), false);
```

Comment: Downvoter: reason? I don't see where my answer is technically incorrect.